# Properties of function based on it's graph

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $f(t) = a(t) + b(t)$ where $t \ge 0$, where $a$ and $b$ are continuous functions.  Suppose we know that $b(t)$ has unbounded variation (as in the path of a Brownian motion).  Suppose we see the graph of $f$ over the interval $[0,T]$.  How (if at all) can we tell if $a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?